# Wordpress, function after 'update user' is clicked

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use wp_mail() after a website administrator edits some details of a user.
When the admin finished updating the details on the EDIT USER page and clicks the 'Update User' button, I want to execute a PHP code, something like -

```
if (some checkings) { wp_mail() }
```

[image]

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, because you have shown _nothing_ whatsoever you have done yourself to try and solve this already. Basically a typical “wish list” posting, and not even close to a question fit for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use profile update function

This hook allows you to access data for a user immediately after their database information is updated.

```
<?php
     add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );
     function my_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
            // Your email function here
        }
    ?>
```

[More info here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Action_Reference/profile_update)