# wordpress: fire function when update any user is clicked

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Related:[Wordpress, function after 'update user' is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041943/wordpress-function-after-update-user-is-clicked)

I have a PHP script that needs to run whenever any user profile is updated in wordpress:

```
function profile_update() {

    echo "<h2>fired on profile update</h2>";
// do stuff
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'profile_update' );
```

but it does not fire when user is updated. what is happening? this hook is supposed to do the job...

expect action hook to work, unclear whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to connect your custom callback to the update user action hook:

```php
add_action('show_user_profile', 'profile_update');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'profile_update');
```

Comment: @postpoopzoomies
I have rectified my answer please check now and please let me know about it.

Comment: hi mate, what was throwing me is that print_r and echo does not work when wrapped in a function, it didnt show up on the front end, so I thought that my code wasnt running. jsut a wordpress thing. your solution means I can see the output from this in the user panel on the back end, and on testing, indeed, it works as expected and what i wanted. thanks!

Comment: @postpoopzoomies anytime mate !!!